# Specific quantifier elimination for real algebraic numbers

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, constraint-satisfaction, smt-solvers, logical-validity

It is well-known that the theory of (first-order) real arithmetic, $\mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{R}}$, is decidable, both on its linear and non-linear (a.k.a field) fragments, since Tarski-Seindenberg proved real closed fields are decidable.

We know this is not so with the theory of non-linear rational arithmetic, $\mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{Q}}$. Indeed, we know the real closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ is the field  of real algebraic numbers, $\mathbb{R}_{\mathbb{A}}$.

My question is the following: is there any effective quantifier elimination method that is **specific** to $\mathbb{R}_{\mathbb{A}}$? I think *Cylindrical Algebraic Decomposition* (CAD) is for general $\mathbb{R}$, but is there any faster method specific to $\mathbb{R}_{\mathbb{A}}$?

In other words, if we say this is the hierarchy:

| Theory | Linear | Non-linear |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $\mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{Q}}$ | Decidable (Ferrante-Rackoff, Fourier-Motzkin) | Undecidable |
| $\mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{R}_{\mathbb{A}}}$ | This is the same as above | Decidable. **Any specific method apart from CAD?** |
| $\mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{R}}$ | This is the same as above | Decidable (CAD) |

I am trying to find a method (that is not CAD) that solves non-linear $\mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{R}_{\mathbb{A}}}$.

Comment: Since $\mathcal T_{\mathbb{R_A}}=\mathcal T_\mathbb R$, how can you expect there to be anything specific to $\mathbb{R_A}$?

Comment: The point is they are not the same: $\mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{R}_{\mathbb{A}}}$ is subsumed by $\mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{R}}$ (then, all the methods for $\mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{R}}$ can be applied to $\mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{R}_{\mathbb{A}}}$). Thus, since $\mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{R}_{\mathbb{A}}}$ is simpler, there should be a simpler method than the one general for $\mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{R}}$.

Comment: They *are* the same theory. They have the same language, they have the same theorems. They are both equal to the theory of real-closed fields. So what do you actually mean?

Comment: I see.. yes. I guess my point was incorrect.

Comment: ([A. Seidenberg](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Seidenberg))